# reached target graphical interface gdm

Tags: xorg, arch-linux

the system freeze in the line "reached target graphical interface" after it do loop of "Starting User Manager for UID 120", "Stopped User Manager for UID 120" and the gdm try to load but I see only the cursor.

I tried also lightdm but I think that the problem is in the xorg. when I try to startx I see a terminal but cant type in this terminal.

This is a log xorg.0.log

```
[  1003.797] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event9)
[  1003.797] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[  1003.797] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[  1003.797] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[  1003.797] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[  1003.797] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event9 13:73 fd 20 paused 0
[  1003.797] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[  1003.797] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  1003.797] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[  1003.797] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[  1003.798] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event9 is a touchpad
[  1003.798] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event9"
[  1003.798] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 9)
[  1003.798] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1003.798] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1003.798] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1003.798] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1003.798] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[  1003.798] (II) input device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad', /dev/input/event9 is a touchpad
[  1003.798] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  1003.798] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[  1003.798] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/event11)
[  1003.798] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[  1003.798] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  1003.799] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event11 13:75 fd 21 paused 0
[  1003.799] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'
[  1003.799] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: always reports core events
[  1003.799] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event11"
[  1003.799] (II) input device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint', /dev/input/event11 is tagged by udev as: Mouse Pointingstick
[  1003.799] (II) input device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint', /dev/input/event11 is a pointer caps
[  1003.799] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input11/event11"
[  1003.799] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[  1003.799] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1003.799] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1003.799] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1003.799] (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1003.799] (II) input device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint', /dev/input/event11 is tagged by udev as: Mouse Pointingstick
[  1003.799] (II) input device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint', /dev/input/event11 is a pointer caps
[  1003.800] (II) config/udev: Adding input device TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint (/dev/input/mouse1)
[  1003.800] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1003.800] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1003.800] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event4)
[  1003.800] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1003.800] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1003.800] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ThinkPad Extra Buttons (/dev/input/event3)
[  1003.800] (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1003.800] (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1003.800] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 22 paused 0
[  1003.800] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons'
[  1003.800] (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: always reports core events
[  1003.800] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  1003.801] (II) input device 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1003.801] (II) input device 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1003.801] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input4/event3"
[  1003.801] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ThinkPad Extra Buttons" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[  1003.801] (II) input device 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1003.801] (II) input device 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1003.801] (II) config/udev: Adding input device BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard (/dev/input/event10)
[  1003.801] (**) BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1003.801] (**) BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1003.801] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event10 13:74 fd 23 paused 0
[  1003.801] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard'
[  1003.802] (**) BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1003.802] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[  1003.802] (II) input device 'BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard', /dev/input/event10 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1003.802] (II) input device 'BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard', /dev/input/event10 is a keyboard
[  1003.802] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input12/event10"
[  1003.802] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[  1003.802] (II) input device 'BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard', /dev/input/event10 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1003.802] (II) input device 'BRLTTY 5.2 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard', /dev/input/event10 is a keyboard
[  1012.797] (**) Option "fd" "15"
[  1012.797] (**) Option "fd" "18"
[  1012.797] (**) Option "fd" "19"
[  1012.798] (**) Option "fd" "20"
[  1012.798] (**) Option "fd" "21"
[  1012.798] (**) Option "fd" "22"
[  1012.798] (**) Option "fd" "23"
[  1012.798] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  1012.825] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
[  1012.825] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:74
[  1012.825] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
[  1012.825] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
[  1012.826] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
[  1012.826] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:73
[  1012.826] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
[  1012.826] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
[  7585.413] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  7585.413] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:74
```

and this is gdm log file

```
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
(II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you read this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Configuration

Comment: yes. but It didnt help